# Copy records from a table of a database to a table of same name of other database through c++

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, eclipse

There is a database named "rfidacs" and there is a table in that database named "Alarm". Now I want to copy all the records of Alarm table to a table of same name "Alarm" of another database named DbDemo. I have written this code. Kindly correct it .I am programming on eclipse IDE on linux.

```
int DBDEMO :: demoTest()


{

MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL *conn, *conn1;

conn  = mysql_init(NULL);
conn1 = mysql_init(NULL);

if(conn == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"mysql_init() failed");
    exit(1);
}
if(conn1 == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"mysql_init() failed");
        exit(1);
    }
if( mysql_real_connect(conn1, "localhost", "root", "rgb123", "DbDemo", 0, NULL, 0)==NULL)
    {
        finish_with_error(conn1);
    }

if( mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "rgb123", "rfidacs", 0, NULL, 0)==NULL)
{
    finish_with_error(conn);
}

if(mysql_query(conn,"select * from Alarm"))
        {
            finish_with_error(conn);
        }
MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(conn);

if(result == NULL)
{
    finish_with_error(conn);
}

int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);


while((row=mysql_fetch_row(result)))
{
    char *temp;
    for(int i=0;i<num_fields;i++)
    {
    temp="Insert into Alarm values (row[i])";
    mysql_query(conn1, temp);
        if(mysql_query(conn1, "Insert into Alarm values row"))
          {
            finish_with_error(conn1);

          }

    }

}

mysql_free_result(result);
mysql_close(conn);
mysql_close(conn1);

}
return SUCCESS;



}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should also avoid using `select * from Alarm` . In particular `*` should be replaced by explicit column names. It is because, there is an unsurity, that the columns may/may not be returned in the same order as they are defined in the table schema. Same would be recommended for `INSERT` statement as well. Explicit column naming is always preferred over `*`.

Comment: there are 40 columns in Alarm table so cant write all the column names explicitely. And I have tried using * , there columns are returning in the same order as they are.

Comment: Well with simple keyboard macro tips and describe like commands of database, you can get all the 40 columns easily. :) I use notepad++ vertical edit and macros for similar purposes. It is good that the columns are being returned in same order, but to be future proof, you should avoid *. All the best for your project.

Comment: okay leaving apart *, can u tell me how to insert the fetched columns into other table of other databse. ?

Comment: I think you should go through prepared statements, it covers almost all sort of insertion problems : (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: can u tell me about how to make a prepared statement through my cpp code ...plz help me I am not getting it

Answer (score 0):

I think [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) is what you are looking for.

You create the "prepared statement" template and pass the row entry as value in each iteration.